# Filter not working on Object with null Value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have already tried and tested many concepts and code snippet but none is working. I want to filter my data (such as if I type 'a' it should return data containing 'a', if no values typed in search box then it should return all the data) Its working fine without any null value in object, but for the 2nd api that is fetching some nullable values its throwing error.

**Code working fine**:

```
 return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        item[key].includes(filterItem));
```

I tried to fix, by removing null value and given only the string data keys, but not working fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Fixes I tried to implement:**

```
Object.keys(item).forEach(k => {
           if (item[k] !== null) {
            console.log(item[k])
             return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
              item[key].includes(filterItem)
            );
          }
   })
```

**Error:**

[image]

Edit:

```js
/* Input Data

const input=[{DeviceType: "CONSUMER", DeviceSubType: "CARD", status: "ACTIVE", categoryname: null, count: 5}
 {DeviceType: "CONSUMER", DeviceSubType: "CARD", status: "AVAILABLE", categoryname: null, count: 2}
2: {DeviceType: "MERCHANT", DeviceSubType: null, status: "ACTIVE", categoryname: "Agent", count: 2}
 {DeviceType: "MERCHANT", DeviceSubType: null, status: "ACTIVE", categoryname: "MerchantOffline", count: 2}
 {DeviceType: "MERCHANT", DeviceSubType: null, status: "ACTIVE", categoryname: "MerchantOnline", count: 1}
 {DeviceType: "MERCHANT", DeviceSubType: null, status: "AVAILABLE", categoryname: null, count: 3}
 {DeviceType: "MERCHANT", DeviceSubType: "XipPOSApp", status: "AVAILABLE", categoryname: null, count: 3}] */
 
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "../css/Search.css"
import ReportList from './reportList'


export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showData: this.props.list,
      filterItem: "",
      filterCount: "initial"
    }
  }


  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      filterItem: e.target.value.toUpperCase(),
      filterCount: "called"
    })

  }



  render() {
    //filtering the data
    const { filterItem, showData } = this.state;

    // console.log(showData)
    const filteredData = showData.filter(item => {

      if (item != null && typeof item != "number") {

        // console.log("item")
        // console.log(item)
        // Object.keys(item).forEach(k => {
        //   if (item[k] !== null && filterItem!==null) {
        //     console.log(item[k])
        //     return Object.keys(item).some(key =>{
        //       console.log(item[key])
        //       item[key].includes(filterItem)
        //     }
           
        //     );
        //   }
        // })

        //working
        return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
         
          item[key].includes(filterItem)
       
          
         
        );
      }
    });
    console.log("filteredData")
    console.log(filteredData)


    const checkValidation = () => {
      if (this.state.filterCount === "initial") {
        return <ReportList data={filteredData} />
      }
      else if (this.state.filterCount === "called") {
        return filteredData != "" ? <ReportList data={filteredData} /> : "NO DATA FOUND"

      }
    }



    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." onChange={this.handleChange} className="search" />
        <div >{checkValidation()} </div>



      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

attached the code snippet with input data
Output: must give card data on typing "ca" in search box

Comment: you can use a ternary operator to check if it's not null then only it will proceed else not. Can you provide a fiddle or something so that one can edit and provide the working code?

Comment: what you want if it's null as includes will not work on null

Comment: Please post a sample of the input, filterItem and the expected output to create a [mcve]

Comment: I have tried conditional statements its getting error or not filtering the data, sure i can provide you the code but its getting data on hitting api so it wont work that way. @AdeshKumar

Comment: just give me with some dummy values.

Comment: Try with `Object.keys(item).some(key => (item[key] || "").includes(filterItem))` or `Object.values(item).some(v => (v || "").includes(filterItem))`

Comment: @adiga if that ```item[key]``` is boolean ```.includes()``` will fail, I think to be safe just check for typeof string.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=erUqsEyuT7  Fiddle Link @AdeshKumar

Comment: your fiddle seems to be empty

Comment: @JuniusL. i dont know much about fiddle, i have edited the post though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to validate your `item[key]`.

```
return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
    (typeof item[key] === 'string' && item[key].includes(filterItem)) 
    || (typeof item[key] === 'number') && item[key] === Number(filterItem))
```

Comment: I think OP is referring to `String.prototype.inludes` and not `Array.prototype.includes`.

Comment: had it before then changed it to check for array.

Comment: @JuniusL. thanks its working fine, but it has integer ,will the filter will work with integer type also?

Comment: @AyushiKeshri so ```item[key]``` can also be an integer?

Comment: I appended typeof item[key] === 'string' || typeof item[key] === 'integer' and tried searching with integer its not working. Its aint working. Also with the target value i am fetching i am converting it to uppercase but if i remove that and search its not showing appropriate data on search

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can also use ```parseInt()``` or ```parseFloat()``` to convert ```filterItem``` to a number.

Comment: @AyushiKeshri you can write also like this way, then no need to bother about other types
`((typeof item[key] !== 'null' || typeof item[key] !== 'undefined') && item[key].includes(filterItem))`

Comment: @tareqaziz you can't use ```.includes()``` on a number or boolean.

Comment: @tareqaziz no its throwing error. I tried to search string only but its showing the same error as above